# Is adding a GPS cradle to the iPod touch worthwhile?

Tags: ipod-touch, gps, geolocation

I am looking for a GPS that will guide me on hikes and travel from point A to point B without loss of signal in remote areas.  I have found this [accessory](http://www.gpscradle.dualav.com/) for the iPod touch that enables GPS location services.  I am looking for other users EXPERIENCE (not opinions) of this accessory and their personal thoughts on using it or other solutions that I can use my iPod as a location/directional device.

My iPod touch is a 3rd gen, however I feel that this is something that would be desired for all gen's (at least for the 4th as well)

Comment: Which gen iPod Touch do you have? the current 4th gen model has full GPS capability built in.

Comment: @Ausmith1 Are you sure? I don't see any reference to it [on Apple's site](http://www.apple.com/ipodtouch/specs.html).

Comment: You are right, I was mistaken. After asking a relative who develops phone firmware and knows this sort of stuff a lot better than I do, he told me that the iPod Touch does not have a real GPS, just cell/wifi triangulation software with a digital compass circuit that drives the location awareness. While the iPhone has a GPS chip it still mainly uses the same. If you are going to be hiking in the wilderness with no cell signals nearby then a base iPod touch will do you no good. You'll need the GPS accessory linked to in the original question to get a real GPS signal to determine your location.

Answer (score 1):

No info to report on the cradle you linked to, but several Bluetooth models work fairly well. Apple apps work the best but some third party mapping apps don't use the GPS as well as the onboard one for the iPhone. Others resist installing as the developers require iPhone or iPad with GPS to install.

It would be best to contact the developer of your mapping app of choice and see what they recommend.

http://www.gns-gmbh.com/ - tested that for a day so it worked but I can't recommend it for the field without more time with it.

[XGPS 150](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004M3BICU) - this worked well but I ultimately sold it since I don't want a short days GPS but a whole weekend to a week so I'm back using my garmin that is all in one and takes AA batteries.